# Show that $X = \{ \text{The set of all series which converge to } a \in [-1,1] \}$ is not compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Show that $X = \{ \text{The set of all series which converge to }a \in [-1,1] \}$ is not compact. The metric on this space is given by $$ d\left(\bar a, \bar b\right)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}| a_k -b_k |^2\right)^{1/2}.$$

My idea was to take $N_r(x_i)$ for some fixed $r$ and $x_i \in X$ to show that the only covering of $X$ requires that  $n \rightarrow \infty$ of $$ \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} N_r(x_i)$$ But, I don't know how to show this. Alternatively, is there another way just based on definition of compactness alone to show that this space is not compact?

Comment: Can you find a sequence in $X$ with no convergent subsequence?

Comment: Well, I proved this space is complete, so I don't think so.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric is most certainly complete and has the sequence $x_n=n$ which does not have a convergent subsequence (and so is not compact). Check your definitions :)

Comment: Oh, my mistake. So, if there is a nonconvergent subsequence in $X$, we have shown that it is not closed $\rightarrow$ not compact?

Comment: If $X$ is complete, then it is closed. Now, A metric space is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded. So it would suffice to show that $X$ is not totally bounded.

Comment: Isn't $X$ totally bounded, for $X \subset N_3(x)$ for some $x \in X$?

Comment: @JMill. No, that just shows it's bounded, not toally bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Take for fixed $n$ the point $e_n$ which is the sequence defined by $(e_n)_n = 1$ and $(e_n)_m = 0$ for $m \neq n$.

All these are simple series that all converge to 1, so they're all in $X$.

The distance $d'(e_n, e_m) = \sqrt{2}$ for $n \neq m$, by simple computation.

Consider $(e_n)$ as a sequence in $X$, and note that if it would have a convergent subsequence (in the whole space or $X$), its terms would have to get closer together (the subsequence is Cauchy..), and this never happens. So $X$ is not sequentially compact (which is equivalent to compact in metric spaces).